# Выбрать все элементы после определенного

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Есть список, мне нужно что бы при наведении мышкой на перый елемент списка подчеркивались все остальные, пытаюсь сделать так:

```js
$('.title_content').hover(function() {
  $(this).nextAll('a').css({
    'text-decoration': 'underline'
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="description">
  <li><a href="#" class="title_content">USER INTERFACE DESIGN</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="remove">Wirefarming</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="remove">Prototyping</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="remove">Usability testing</a></li>
</ul>
```

Но ничего не получается, подскажите в чем проблема?

Вот как это должно быть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$().nextAll` - выбирает элементы в том же родителе.

```js
$('.title_content').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('li').nextAll('li').find('a').css({
    'text-decoration': 'underline'
  });
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="description">
  <li><a href="#" class="title_content">USER INTERFACE DESIGN</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="remove">Wirefarming</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="title_content">Prototyping</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="remove">Usability testing</a></li>
</ul>
```